# Is it ok to define multiple NCLOB columns in an oracle table?

Tags: oracle

I've got to store multiple text fields of variable length in an oracle database. I'd need to define them as columns of the same table to be able to order the results when I query it.

I can't know the max size of the field contents, most of them will be less than 100 characters but there could be some of thousands of chars. Furthermore the number of fields changes dinamically.

I was thinking of defining a table with multiple NCLOB columns that would allow me to store anything in them (very short and very long texts) But I wonder if this would be the right design.

Summary:

- Variable number of fields (metadata of the same object)
- Variable length of the content
- I need to order the results

Thanks

KL

Answer (score 1):

When you need variable number of fields, it's better to split the table into parent and child. Then you can effectively have any number of fields. And you can add order column to store ordering information to order the result. You can query by joining the two table and use `order by` clause to order the result. Also you can add foreign key constraint to make sure the relationship and data integrity.

In the case of variable length of contents, you can use varchar2(or nvarchar2) to store text date. Varchar2 can hold characters up to 4000 bytes. If you know that the maximum length of the content can be longer than 4000 bytes, you should use CLOB(or NCLOB).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

You mean something like this?

Parent table: 
- ID
- [ORDER-COLUMN]?

Fields table:
- ID

Children table
- PARENT_ID (FK)
- FIELD_ID (FK)
- VALUE (NCLOB or NVARCHAR2 depending on length)


For the ordering, I understood you meant to add a ORDER-COLUMN to the parent table? If so, it wouldn't do, cause I need to filter by any field.

Also, there is no problem in defining NCLOBs columns to store in the 90% of the cases short texts?

select * from PARENT P
left join CHILDREN C on P.ID = C.PARENT_ID
where C.VALUE = 'xxx'
order by ???

Comment: Parent table P would have columns like (id, ...) and child table C would have columns like (id, value, ord). Data type of each column omitted. id in C would be FK to P. As you can see, order column (ord) is in child table. Your query can be written like this: SELECT * FROM p LEFT JOIN c on (p.id = c.id) where ... order by ord;